# Ribbon group doesn't display in Outlook 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio, outlook, vsto

I created an add-in for Outlook 2007/2010. There are 2 ribbons one for the compose window and the other is for the read window. There are 2 groups on each ribbon. In outlook 2007 they both display as expected but in 2010 the first one is always missing.

why is this? How can I prevent this from happeneing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to NOT put any controls in the menu controls or list type of controls in the designer, but do it via code. Pain to do it that way but the XML generated by the designer is flawed and has a problem running in outlook 2010. I changed it to all run via code and everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `idMso` properties for each tab in the Ribbon XML. The correct idMso for the existing Compose ribbon tab in the Inspector is `TabNewMailMessage`.

If that doesn't work, check the `RibbonType` property on the Ribbon itself to make sure it is enabled on the two Inspectors you are targeting.

Comment: the ribbon and tabs are showing, the problem is the groups. The first group doesn't display. I've already found a potential solution: Populate drop downs at runtime because the xml for the ribbon is invalid otherwise. Waiting to hear back if it worked.

Comment: Oh, I see. Would it be possible for you to post the Ribbon XML? Or just the XML for the two groups?